# Proving that a group homomorphism preserves associativity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism, associativity

I felt this was trivial, but I wanted to make sure. The proofs I've read which show that the image of a group homomorphism is a subgroup of its codomain only prove that closure, identity, and inverse are preserved in the image. I wrote this fast proof to see if this is a correct way to show that associativity is also always preserved:

---

Let $(G , \times)$ and $(H, \dot \times)$ be groups and let $G \xrightarrow{\quad \varphi \quad} H$ be a homomorphism.
If $a, b , c\in \mathrm{im}\varphi$ then there exist elements $a', b', c' \in G$ such that $\varphi(a') = a$ and $\varphi(b') =b$ and $\varphi(c') = c$. Then since group homomorphisms must preserve the group operation:

$(a \times b) = (\varphi(a') \dot \times \varphi(b')) = \varphi(a' \times b')$.

Similarly,

$(b \times c) = (\varphi(b') \dot \times \varphi(c')) = \varphi(b' \times c')$.

Now, we know also that

$ (a' \times b') \times c' = a' \times (b' \times c')$

which implies:

$\varphi((a' \times b') \times c') = \varphi(a' \times b') \dot \times \varphi(c') = (\varphi(a') \dot \times \varphi(b')) \dot \times \varphi(c') = (a \dot \times b) \dot \times c$

Similarly,

$\varphi(a' \times (b' \times c')) = \varphi(a') \dot \times \varphi(b' \times c') = \varphi(a') \dot \times (\varphi(b') \dot \times \varphi(c')) = a \dot \times (b \dot \times c)$

A homomorphism is a function, thus no element in the domain can map to multiple points in the codomain.

Since our homomorphism is a function we know then that $(a \dot \times b) \dot \times c = a \dot \times (b \dot \times c)$

---

I apologize if this was not the most concise way to prove things, I did not see this proved online after doing a bit of searching, and wanted to check quickly. Thank you for looking.

Comment: Associativity is not part of the condition for being a subgroup.

Comment: If it is a group homomorphism, then $H$ is a group, so why wouldn't $(a\times b)\times c=a\times(b\times c)$ just follow from the definition of group? I am confused by what is supposed to be learned here.

Comment: I guess if you have $H$ a not-necessarily-associative operation with identity and inverses, call it an na-group, and $G$ is a group, then a homomorphism of na-groups $G\to H$ has associativity in the image.

Comment: Associativity is a property of the operation of $H$, not of the homomorphism. You don't "preserve" properties of the operation, you preserve the operation itself.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: A magma in which you have an identity and inverses, but the operation is not necessarily associative, already has a name: they are called [loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup).

Comment: I sort of assumed it might have a name, but I didn't want to look it up.  @ArturoMagidin